# Prove or disprove this equation has infinitely many solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove or disprove following equation has infinitely many integer solutions in $\mathbb Z$:

$x^2+y^2-29t^2-40t=29$

$x^2+y^2=29t+40t+29=(25t^2+20t+4)+(4t^2+20t+25)$

$x^2=(5t+2)^2$ ⇒ $x=±(5t+2)$

$y^2=(2t+5)^2$ ⇒ $y=±(2t+5)$

The equation is symmetric for x and y, so are the solutions.Hence this equation has infinitely many solutions.

Is this solution reasonable? Is there a direct method for prove or disprove this?

Comment: for each integer $t$, there are 4 pairs of solutions. And there are infinitely many integer choices of $t$, so...

Comment: Thee are more solutions, such as $x=9, y=12, t=2$.  But you only need one infinite set and you have found one